# How to set string from sqlite to Spinner in Android?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have **Spinner** in my app and set String[] programmatic.

```
speciality = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.general_specality_s);
specialityadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, speciality_list);
speciality.setAdapter(specialityadapter);
```

and get selected string like this `speciality.getSelectedItem().toString();` and store in **sqlite.**  Now I want to get that value from **sqlite** and need to set in **Spinner1.**

```
String SpinnerText=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("speciality"));
```

How to set this string to **speciality / Spinner** ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch your data into an array and use an array adapter

```
String[] spinnerArray = your data goes here;
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yourspinnerid);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, this is working fine and me already used like that only for creating a record that is fresh. Now I need to edit a record that stored. In that time spinner item having or hold only one string and i get that string using `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SpinnerText"));` Now i need to this string to that spinner ?